# Pyspark - Create new column with the RMSE of two other columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am fairly new to Pyspark. I have a dataframe, and I would like to create a 3rd column with the calculation for RMSE between `col1` and `col2`. I am using a user defined lambda function to make the RMSE calculation, but keep getting this error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'mean'`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "30g").appName('linear_data_pipeline').getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
old_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(
    [(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 5)]), ('col_1', 'col_2'))
function = udf(lambda col1, col2 : (((col1 - col2)**2).mean())**.5)
new_df = old_df.withColumn('col_n',function(col('col_1'), col('col_2')))
new_df.show()
```

How do I best go about fixing this issue?
I would also like to find the RMSE/mean, mean absolute error, mean absolute error/mean, median absolute error, and Median Percent Error, but once I figure out how to calculate one, I should be good on the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a `udf` in that case. I think it is possible by using only `pyspark.sql.functions`.

I can propose you the following untested option

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

rmse = old_df.withColumn("squarederror",
                   psf.pow(psf.col("col1") - psf.col("col2"),
                           psf.lit(2)
                  ))
       .agg(psf.avg(psf.col("squarederror")).alias("mse"))
       .withColumn("rmse", psf.sqrt(psf.col("mse")))

rmse.collect()
```

Using the same logic, you can get other performance statistics

Comment: How would I do this with a groupby though? Say I want to calculate the RMSE for each month of a year like this `df_month = my_df.groupby('month').agg(rmse(my_df, 'col1', 'col2'))`

Comment: I gave you the answer to the [other SO question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175772/pyspark-calculate-rmse-between-actuals-and-predictions-for-a-groupby-asserti/61175948#61175948). To help users to find the most appropriate answer to this question, you should accept one of the answers given (the one from @Cristian Contrera or mine, depending on the one that satisfies you the most)

Answer (score 1):

I think than you are some confused.
The [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) is calculated from a succession of points, therefor you don't must calculate this for each value in two columns.
I think you have to calculate RMSE using all values in each column.

This could works:

```
pow = udf(lambda x: x**2)
rmse = (sum(pow(old_df['col1'] - old_df['col2']))/len(old_df))**.5
print(rmse)
```

Comment: How would I do this with a groupby though? Say I want to calculate the RMSE for each month of a year like this `df_month = my_df.groupby('month').agg(rmse(my_df, 'col1', 'col2'))`