# How to record each epoch RMSE using ALS in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, collaborative-filtering

Based on the tutorial from pyspark. I am trying to create a recommendation system using pyspark with RMSE as the evaluation metric. I would like to record the RMSE for each training epoch. However, the epoch number is enter when I create the ALS object and it seems that I can only print RMSE value after the training is done. May I please ask how I can print each epoch's RMSE using ALS from pyspark?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-collaborative-filtering.html

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example or the structure of the data it is hard to be specific. So I can propose you something about RMSE [from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175772/pyspark-calculate-rmse-between-actuals-and-predictions-for-a-groupby-asserti/61175948#61175948)
but more details might be needed:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

def compute_RMSE(expected_col, actual_col, group_col):

  rmse = old_df.withColumn("squarederror",
                           psf.pow(psf.col(actual_col) - psf.col(expected_col),
                                   psf.lit(2)
                           ))
  .groupby(group_col)
  .agg(psf.avg(psf.col("squarederror")).alias("mse"))
  .withColumn("rmse", psf.sqrt(psf.col("mse")))

  return(rmse)
```

And you could call the function like that (here some details might help to be more specific)

```py
compute_RMSE("expectedcol", "realizedcol","epoch")
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I am following this code template as showed in the link: